# SparkSQL cannot run a simple SQL query

Tags: sql, select, apache-spark-sql

I am working with a simple SparkSQL query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    (DATE + DURATION) AS EXPIRY_MONTH
FROM
    loan
WHERE
    EXPIRY_MONTH >= 12
```

where the first 10 lines of `loan` table are the following:

```
"loan_id";"account_id";"date";"amount";"duration";"payments";"status"
5314;1787;930705;96396;12;8033.00;"B"
5316;1801;930711;165960;36;4610.00;"A"
6863;9188;930728;127080;60;2118.00;"A"
5325;1843;930803;105804;36;2939.00;"A"
7240;11013;930906;274740;60;4579.00;"A"
6687;8261;930913;87840;24;3660.00;"A"
7284;11265;930915;52788;12;4399.00;"A"
6111;5428;930924;174744;24;7281.00;"B"
7235;10973;931013;154416;48;3217.00;"A"
```

This query works how intented with SQLite (meaning that the column `EXPIRY_MONTH` is added and data are filtered on the condition `EXPIRY_MONTH >= 12`)  but not with SparkSQL (Spark 3.1.0).

Specifically, the SparkSQL engine throws errore as the `EXPIRY_MONTH` column does not exist.

How can I fix this query without resorting to subqueries?

What is the reason of this behaviour and difference between SparkSQL and more standard SQL?

Answer (score 0):

you are not able to run this query as spark is lazily evaluated and it won't find that column that you are creating in the where clause.

What you can do is you can use the same logic which you are applying to create the separate column in the where clause which will allow you to run the query without using subquery.

```
SELECT
    *,
    (DATE + DURATION) AS EXPIRY_MONTH
FROM
    loan
WHERE
    (DATE + DURATION) >= 12
```